# Setup rabbitmq on kubernetes fails with error- cannot touch '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf': Permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to setup [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html) on my aks cluster running on 1.27.7.

This my rabbitmq yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
 name: production-rabbitmqcluster
spec:
 replicas: 3
 resources:
   requests:
     cpu: 500m
     memory: 1Gi
   limits:
     cpu: 1
     memory: 2Gi
 rabbitmq:
   additionalConfig: |
     log.console.level = info
     channel_max = 1700
     default_user = guest
     default_pass = guest
     default_user_tags.administrator = true
 service:
   type: LoadBalancer
```

I have created my secret and config file and applied it but getting below error-

```
touch: cannot touch '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf': Permission denied

WARNING: '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf' is not writable, but environment variables have been provided which request that we write to it

We have copied it to '/tmp/rabbitmq.conf' so it can be amended to work around the problem, but it is recommended that the read-only

source file should be modified and the environment variables removed instead.
```

Can someone suggest a fix or a workaround?

Comment: Have you read https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html#psp?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Andromeda, I checked it, as per rabbitmq's doc the config must be read-write, i checked my config has rw permission.

Comment: The error message you're seeing suggests that the RabbitMQ container is trying to write to the rabbitmq.conf file in the /etc/rabbitmq/ directory, but it does not have the necessary permissions to do so. This is a common issue when the Docker image has been configured to run as a non-root user for security reasons. You can define a securityContext for your RabbitMQ pod that allows it to write to the necessary directories. However values will depend on the user and group IDs that your RabbitMQ image expects to run or Instead of this you can try deploying it via helmchart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-order to configure rabbitMQ on AKS, kindly follow below steps-
Here I will be using bitnami charts for rabbitMQ for the setup.

1. Assuming that you have a working AKS cluster with helm installed on it as below.
   [image]

[image]

2. Run `helm list` command to verify if any charts already present. If not, you will search for the rabbitmq repo using `helm search repo rabbitmq` , add the repo using `helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami`, update the repo to keep things upto-date using `helm repo update` and verify your rabbitMQ details using `helm show values bitnami/rabbitmq`
3. Now install the rabbitMQ using `helm install my-release bitnami/rabbitmq`.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Once installed, you will get your login credentials on your screen. Save them and map your ports as shown above using `kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/my-release-rabbitmq 15672:15672`
   Once the port is mapped, you should see something like this-
   [image]

Now go to your browser and type `localhost:15672`
and you are on the login page of rabbitMQ
[image]

5. Key in the credentials which you have saved from your previous step and you have successfully logged into rabbitMQ dashboard.
   [image]